# Quoting project IDs in TABLE_DATE_RANGE in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to specify a project name using the TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in BigQuery.

I've typically used TABLE_DATE_RANGE only specifying the dataset and table names as

```
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(dataset1.table1, TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -365, "DAY")), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, "DAY"))
```

But I can't figure out how to specify the project name too.  I've tried

```
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(project1:dataset1.table1, TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -365, "DAY")), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, "DAY"))
```

But that gives me the following error

> Error in query string: Error processing job
>   'rhi-localytics-db:bqjob_r280f0878_0000015578e6271e_1': Can't parse table: project1:dataset1.table1

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Ultimately the problem I was encountering wasn't exclusively caused by the double colons (cause I had tried both with single and double colons, as I'd seen double colon usage in an example elsewhere on the web), and it also wasn't exclusively caused by the lack of quoting.  It was caused because what I thought was the project name was actually just the project title in the BigQuery web interface page as opposed to the actual project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the table identifier with brackets when it contains `:`, or any other special characters that may appear in project IDs.

```
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project1:dataset1.table1], TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -365, "DAY")), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, "DAY"))
```

---

Actually, looking at the internal details for your query based on the job ID you linked, it looks like there are multiple errors with the specified project name.

- You used two colons instead of one when separating the project (e.g. `project::dataset.table` should be `project:dataset.table`).
- You've capitalized the project name, but project names can only contain lowercase characters (and some symbols).
- Even if you remove the capital letter, the project does not appear to exist.

Comment: I didn't specify the project name, someone else did and the project name definitely has a capital in it.  Do we have to rename the project to exclude capitals.

Comment: I am an idiot. I was using the display name and not the project name.  Thank you.